# Can Excel Prioritize?

Tags: excel

I have to preface this with the fact that I have never used VBA.  I am trying to pull information based on priority into separate tabs.

i.e. on one tab I have 'priority' as a column (1 through 5) with store numbers falling into each priority category going across.  Sometimes only 1 store falls into the #1 top priority, 3 into the 2 priority, etc and the number of stores in each category could change month to month.

I want to pull the store number onto separate tabs (day 1, day 2, day 3) to help people prioritize their week.

Is there a way that Excel can select in a logical order going down rows and putting them consecutively on different tabs?

I've been trying for hours and no luck, searching the internet is only giving me 'how to prioritize your to do list with Excel'!

Comment: You need to provide more information than this.  Please show us what you have already tried.

Comment: You can porobably do something using `vlookup` or `hlookup` to make a column that depends on another table and then sort with this. I need more information to provide a more complete solution

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to view the data on the "day" tabs (not modify), you could make a pivot table on each tab with a filter for the store number.

Let's assume you have all the information on tab "Data", and want to present it on three tabs named "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3". You then create three pivot tables (one on each tab), and all should take data from the same data source (the "Data" tab). Every time you modify the information on "Data", you will have to go to each "Day"-tab and update the pivot table.